# How often does the DNS cache clear?

Tags: windows-7, dns, cache

How often does the DNS cache clear on a Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The DNS cache doesn't ever flush, unless you explicitly tell it to or you make a DNS/networking related configuration change.  DNS records have a Time To Live (TTL) value associated with them which tells a DNS cache how long the particular record is good for.  Records in the cache are kept for their TTL, then re-queried.

On a Windows machine you can see a list of all the records in your cache along with their TTL by executing the following command at the command prompt:

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

You can force a flush of all cached DNS records using the following command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

For more info:

- [Wikipedia article on DNS and TTLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Caching_and_time_to_live)

Comment: What kind of things constitute a "networking change"? A new IP address, joining a different wifi network? or manually flushing the cache / setting DNS

Comment: According to the other answers (and common sense), it appears like there is indeed a maximum lifetime for cached DNS entries in Windows. Consider the opposite: It would then be trivial for websites to perform a denial-of-service attack against visitors by triggering a huge number of DNS queries over time, until Windows runs out of HDD/RAM/CPU because of the ever-increasing cache size. So this answer seems wrong.

Comment: @Zero3 That can be explained via a per-entry TTL (which may have a maximum value such that no entry is held over this time; the answer does not claim that there cannot be a maximum TTL). Thus the answer *can* be true, in it's assertion that there is no *"[entire] cache flush"*, while still explaining the counter-argument behavior because entries are "flushed" (expired) individually by their own TTL entries .. granted, a little bit of wording cleanup might help.

Answer (score 12):

From what I've been able to find, Windows 7 does not set a parameter for dnscache [MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959517.aspx).

The default value for MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit is `DWORD = 0x15180 = 86400 seconds = 1 day`

- if DNS zone TTL < MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit, then DNS TTL is used
- if DNS zone TTL > MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit, then MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit is used

Answer (score 8):

#### According to: [Reduce DNS Client Cache in Windows Server 2012 R2](http://www.isolation.se/reduce-dns-client-cache-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Instead of [`MaxCacheEntryTtlLimit`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959517.aspx) you should modify [`maxcacheTTL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959926.aspx). It works for Windows 8 too.

> #### Description
>
> Determines how long the Domain Name System (DNS) server can save a record of a recursive name query.
>
> If the value of this entry is 0x0, the DNS server does not save any records.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. One more thing to add from that blog post run ```net stop dnscache & net start dnscache``` to make setting take without rebooting.

Comment: For what it looks like, maxcacheTTL is for the "DNS server" component of Windows Server, not for the DNS Cache.