# How to check Internet browsing history through cmd or powershell on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I would like to check a machine's Internet browsing history and I would like to do this from the the command line or PowerShell.

Are there any Windows commands or tools for doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can view cached DNS entries from CMD.

Every time you browse to a web page, your PC has to request the IP Address for that web site from your default DNS server, and then caches them locally on your machine for a while to speed up future access to that web site — even in a private browsing session.

You can see these for yourself by opening up a command prompt and typing in `ipconfig /displaydns` to see the full list of cached DNS entries.

Now, the first thing you’ll notice is that a whole lot of information will appear, to the point that all of it can’t fit in the command prompt.  What you can do is take the output of the command and send it to a text file somewhere on your machine.

`ipconfig /displaydns > c:\desired location`

Now, when you open that file you’ll see information about the websites you've visited directly or indirectly.

To get rid of this, just type the command `ipconfig /flushdns` and your DNS cache will be cleared.

**Angel Luis** has written a nice [tutorial and script on this topic](http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7security/hack-private-browsing-mode/), I suggest you read it.

Comment: DNS records returned by `ipconfig /displaydns` are subject to [expiration](https://superuser.com/q/80744/213131) after a time, and other events (such as a reboot) will clear the cache as well. This method's ability to access browsing history is limited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check out [Nirsoft's IEHistoryView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iehv.html), as it allows saving the resutls to a text file:

> This utility reads all information from the history file on your
>   computer, and displays the list of all URLs that you have visited in
>   the last few days. It also allows you to select one or more URL
>   addresses, and then remove them from the history file or save them
>   into text, HTML or XML file. In addition, you are allowed to view the
>   visited URL list of other user profiles on your computer, and even
>   access the visited URL list on a remote computer, as long as you have
>   permission to access the history folder.

Comment: There's *MozillaHistoryView* as well.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, this will display just the DNS names:

```
ipconfig /displaydns|?{$_ -like "Record Name"}
```

And this will display the IP and Record Type:

```
ipconfig /displaydns|?{$_ -like "Record"}
```

Type 1 is an A record and type 5 is an alias.

Comment: Which could also be done in the Command shell as

ipconfig /displaydns |find "Record Name"
and
ipconfig /displaydns |find "Record"

Answer (score 0):

I like the Ipconfig use, but Powershell does have its own code

```
Get-DnsClientCache | Select-Object -Property Entry, Data | Sort-Object Entry | FT
```